# How to show $D(\lambda_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, \lambda_{\sigma(n)} )$ is similar to $D(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $D(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$ denote the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix whose $(i,i)$ entry is $\lambda_i$.

For any permutation,  $\sigma \in S_n$, I want to show that $D(\lambda_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, \lambda_{\sigma(n)} )$ is similar to $D(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$ where $S_n$ means the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

Intuitively, since $D(\lambda_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, \lambda_{\sigma(n)} )$ is nothing but shuffling the order of diagonal matrix, I know it is diagonal but have no idea to show this is similar to $D(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$

Comment: Let $P$ a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), consider $PDP^{-1}$.

Comment: Having same Jordan canonical form...